# Building the inverse

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, inverse, inverse-function, economics

If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are dependent, let $a_2$ be fixed at $\bar{a}_2$

$x_2= x_2(\bar{a}_2,\theta_2) \rightarrow  \theta_2 =x_2^{-1}(\bar{a}_2,x_2)$

Why can you build the inverse dependend on $x_2$?

Thank you :)

[Here is the inverse in the proof i try to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9auog.png)

Comment: Isn't it just because $x_2$ is monotone in $\theta_2$? (That is an assumption of the theorem.) Presumably here "monotone" means strictly monotone (i.e. strictly increasing or decreasing) as this guarantees existence of an inverse.

Comment: yes that could be true. Thanks! I don't quite understand why the inverse is then given with $\theta_2 =x_2^{-1}(\bar{a}_2,x_2)$ and not with $\theta_2 =x_2^{-1}(\bar{a}_2,\theta_2)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function $g$ has an inverse $g^{-1}$, then by definition:
$$g^{-1}(g(z))=z.$$

The proof refers to the inverse of $x_1$ with respect to its second coordinate $\theta_1$. The inverse of $x_1$ with respect to $\theta_1$ exists because $x_1$ is (strictly) monotone in $\theta_1$. The inverse $x_1^{-1}$ of $x_1$ must satisfy $$x_1^{-1}(a_1,x_1(a_1,\theta_1))=\theta_1.$$ In the linked image, the argument $(a_1,\theta_1)$ of $x_1$ has been suppressed:

$$x_1^{-1}(a_1,x_1)=\theta_1.$$